# CSS style for copying rendered HTML page

Tags: html, css, copy, paste

Is there a way to adapt CSS (add some keyword) for copying rendered HTML page?
Like there is way to make CSS for mobile device or for printing I need similar thing for copying for pasting in Word or Excel.

Example is:
I have a page that I need to copy and paste to Word for report but on that page there are input tags that I don't need in report.
There is a JS hack for this but is there some CSS way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit confused with your question. 
You could copy and paste and delete the input tags manually. Have you tried including a CSS print media query to your code and excluding the input boxes?

```
@media print {
    /* something like this */
    input {display:none;}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@L_A_W
I did tired that but when I do "Select All" (Ctrl+A) on page and Paste it to Word I get input tags pasted in Word document that I don't need there.

When I print the page, I can print it to PDF (for example) without input tags, css "@media print" is working for this, but I need to edit report data before sending report.

I need:

```
@media copy {
    .some_element {
        display: none;
    }
}
```